# extract MSChart array from a session

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, mschart

I am trying to save an array of type "Chart"(MSChart) into a session so that I can access my charts anywhere in my ASP application. However, an error is always instantiated whenever I try to bind the any of those saved charts into a single chart control.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart[] c =  (System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart[])Session["PersonnelAdmin"];

    if (Session["PersonnelAdmin"] != null)
    {
        this.Chart1 = c[0];
    }
```

any idea on how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are trying to store a web control in the session, but you can only store objects that are serializable in the session and `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart` is not serializable. Perhaps you should change your application logic to load the required elements from session instead of trying to store the control in the session.